# Store data multiple times when clicking on a button in android studio

Tags: java, android

Always when I click on the button it stores the first textinput in my database. So for example I type for product 'apples' and for quantity '5' and click add. After that I type 'patatoes' '5'. In my database it shows two rows of 'apples' '5' and same id off course. (Don't check ; and { and variable names, I just paste a small part of my code and translated in english quickly.

```
addproduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String article  = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.orderarticleinput)).getText().toString();
                String quantity =((EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantityinput)).getText().toString();

                addarticleurl = addarticlurl + "/" + artikel + "/" +  hoeveelheid + "/" + bestellingsid;
                RequestQueue requestQueue = newRequestQueue(ClientOrder.this);
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, addartikelurl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) { } }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.orderarticleinput)).getText().clear();
                ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantityinput)).getText().clear();


            }

        });
```

Comment: As a side note: Use consistent names (I prefer english caus the framworks are english too) and camelCase to improve maintainability.

Comment: Hi Michiel, I am modarating your question, I think other users will enjoy if you format your code in a better way. About your problem: I think you should debug inside `requestQueue` and check the request parameters on your backend